# Why is MySQL sending the client side a false boolean even though the database itself says true?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to build a React app where a boolean of onboard dictates the render through user authentication and using sequelize. If a user has a false onboard, they are shown the on boarding component. If the user has a true onboard, they are sent to the member homepage instead. I use a state which is grabbed from `req.user` using passport, and my model looks like this:

```
// Requiring bcrypt for password hashing. Using the bcryptjs version as the regular bcrypt module sometimes causes errors on Windows machines
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
// Creating our User model
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define("User", {
        //Id of User
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        // If authenticated through google, a googleId will appear here
        googleId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        // The email cannot be null, and must be a proper email before creation
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            validate: {
                isEmail: true
            }
        },
        // The password cannot be null
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: 'password'
        },
        // Username chosen 
        userName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        //user profile image - String for now ?? Discuss how to do this
        profileImage: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        onboard: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: false
        }
    });

    // Creating a custom method for our User model. This will check if an unhashed password entered by the user can be compared to the hashed password stored in our database
    User.prototype.validPassword = function (password) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
    };

    // Hooks are automatic methods that run during various phases of the User Model lifecycle
    // In this case, before a User is created, we will automatically hash their password
    User.addHook("beforeCreate", function (user) {
        user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
    });

    User.associate = models => {
        User.belongsToMany(models.Games, { through: 'UserGames' });
        User.belongsToMany(models.Chat, { through: 'UserChats' });
    };

    return User;
};
```

During the onboard process, once a user submits, a PUT gets sent to the database to change the onboard from false to true, and therefore also changing the state in react from false to true. However, what I'm finding is that even though mySQL has a value of 1 (which is supposed to be true) that was changed from 0, the req.user is still sending a boolean of false for onboard, I tested this over and over for several minutes, watching the onboard say 1 but returning a false in req.user in the console.log in my terminal. Why does it keep returning false if it's supposed to be true?

Comment: Where is your code that sets the state?

Comment: Maybe this FALSE means "some error occures during quering"? Test, does the return type is rowset, not scalar boolean...

Comment: Have you tried using DataTypes.TINYINT instead of DataTypes.BOOLEAN?

Comment: I didn't post the code to the state because I didn't think the state was the problem. The console log in the terminal is returning false on the server end.